# Why would QueryInterface() fail when the interface is surely implemented and has built-in marshaller in Windows?

Tags: c++, com, marshalling, atl, com+

I have the following setup. There's a COM server that is installed into COM+ (to run in a separate process) and has this interface definition:

```
[object, uuid("InterfaceIdHere"), nonextensible, oleautomation, hidden]
interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
   HRESULT MyMethod( [in] IUnknown* param );
};
```

The caller calls it like this:

```
HRESULT callComObject(IStream* stream)
{
    return comObject->MyMethod(stream);
}
```

Note that here `IStream*` is implicitly upcasted to `IUnknown*`. This is done because declaring a parameter of type `IStream*` in IDL caused some problems that I can't recall right now. Anyway it's always a valid `IStream*` that is passed in place of `IUnknown*`.

The COM server side has this implementation of `MyMethod()`:

```
STDMETHODIMP CServer::MyMethod(IUnknown* param)
{
    if(param == 0) {
       return E_INVALIDARG;
    }   
    ATL::CComQIPtr<IStream> stream(param);
    if(stream == 0) {
       return E_INVALIDARG;// control passes HERE
    }
    // whatever
}
```

So I have `IStream*` passed into `callComObject()` on the client side which is implicitly upcasted to `IUnknown*` and the latter is passed to the COM marshaller. The marshalled `IUnknown*` reaches the server in another process and there `IUnknown*` is obtained and then there's a `QueryInterface()` call to marshall `IStream*` from the same object and that `QueryInterface()` fails.

This looks insane, because marshalling `IStream*` should just work at all times - there's a marshaller for this interface pre-installed in Windows.

Why could it possible not work and how do I find the reason?

Comment: Call `QueryInterface()` directly instead of using `CComQIPtr` and then you can check what `HRESULT` value it is actually returning.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The HRESULT is `E_NOINTERFACE`.

Comment: Are you using the implicit OLEAUT marshaler? or a custom proxy/stub? Is the standard OLEAUT marshaler supposed to marshal anything else that Variant Types if it's not aware (ie: if the idl/typelib doesn't say anything about it)

Comment: @SimonMourier: I rely on OleAut marshaller, there's no custom proxy/stub.

Comment: "IStream* is implicitly upcasted to IUnknown*". If you had done that via COM, i.e. via `IStream::QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown)`, you'd have AddRef'ed the new interface. Are you by any chance releasing the stream too early?

Comment: @MSalters: My code is also a kind of a server that's called from somewhere and that somewhere manages the `IStream*`-pointed object. So I guess the answer is I have no idea about the object lifetime. I guess, calling extra `AddRef()` would not hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the possible scenarios that matches the behavior is the following:

- you don't have any marhshaling between caller and callee
- the interface pointer is valid
- however the object which implements `IStream`, does not have a corresponding `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY` map entry and does not make the interface available, the caller might have obtained the pointer via non-COM way, e.g. direct C++ cast

This is easy to check by `QueryInterface`'ing the stream on the caller side before the call.

The callee in this scenario can just `reinterpret_cast` to `IStream` and have it nicely working.

Comment: It's indeed a good idea to check if you can QI the `IStream*` in the absence of marshalling.

Answer (score 2):

You can either have your IDL import objidl.idl, or define IStream (and ancestors) manually in your own IDL (just be sure to use the standard IID value for it). Then you can use IStream instead of IUnknown as your parameter type and not worry about `QueryInterface()` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

you may replace IUnknown by IDispatch as parameter type of your method. In my mind, the server actually has a stub instead of the stream itself since it is in another process.

this is just a guess

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it only has a stub, but `QueryInterface()` should be forwarded to the client side and retrieve the right interface and get it back.