# Can I use "exclude" with #import directive when I encounter C4192 warning?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, typelib

I have the following IDL:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[uuid(MyLibUuid), version(1.0)]
library MyLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
[object, uuid("MyInterfaceUuid"), nonextensible]
interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
        HRESULT MyMethod( [in] IStream* stream );
    };
}
```

which is compiled into a .tlb file and imported from another project:

```
#import "PathToTypeLib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

and when this is compiled Visual Studio emits the following output:

```
warning C4192: automatically excluding 'IStream'
    while importing type library 'PathToTypeLib.tlb'
warning C4192: automatically excluding 'ISequentialStream'
    while importing type library 'PathToTypeLib.tlb'
```

Okay, the problem is because those to `importlib` directives caused `IStream` and `ISequentialStream` defined inside the typelib - [MSDN explains it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7xdw6y9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and says I have to either use `include` or `no_auto_exclude` with `#import`.

If I use either `no_auto_exclude` or `include( "IStream", "ISequentialStream" )` I now have two `IStream` definitions - one in global namespace and another in typelib namespace and so my code that tries to call `MyMethod` doesn't compile - the compiler says

```
error C2664: 'MyLibrary::MyInterface::MyMethod' :
   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'IStream *' to 'MyLibrary::IStream *'
   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
   C-style cast or function-style cast
```

so it looks like I instead have to use `exclude( "IStream", "ISequentialStream" )` - this way it compiles fine and looks working.

Is using `exclude` actually the right solution?

Comment: Either use exclude or no_namespace.  Favor exclude.

Answer (score 0):

This would work well if `IStream` itself was on a type library, such as `stdole2.tlb` you reference from your IDL/TLB.

Unfortunately it is not and what takes place is that ID: compiler needs to put put your `IMyInterface` onto library block and since `IStream` is referenced, compiler puts it onto type library as well. Hence, the duplicated declaration hurting you once you import the type library back. I don't think you can have it as `IStream` there without taking your own `IStream` interface onto the type library.

The workaround I use is to avoid using `IStream` on method parameters, and to use `IUnknown` there instead. Caller and callee would cast/QI the pointers if/when appropriate. This way it is safe with `#import` and works out in general.

```c
[uuid(MyLibUuid), version(1.0)]
library MyLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
[object, uuid("MyInterfaceUuid"), nonextensible]
interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
        HRESULT MyMethod( [in] IUnknown* pStreamUnkown ); // Instead of IStream
    };
}
```

Caller:

```c
CComPtr<IStream> pStream;
pMyInterface->MyMethod(pStream);
```

Callee:

```c
STDMETHOD(MyMethod)(IUnkown* pStreamUnknown)
{
    CComQIPtr<IStream> pStream = pStreamUnknown;
```

Callee assuming no marshaling (least overhead):

```c
STDMETHOD(MyMethod)(IUnkown* pStreamUnknown)
{
    ATLASSERT((IUnknown*) (IStream*) CComQIPtr<IStream>(pStreamUnknown) ==
      pStreamUnknown);
    const CComPtr<IStream>& pStream = 
      reinterpret_cast<const CComPtr<IStream>&>(pStreamUnknown);
```

Comment: Ouch. This last snippet is Bad Idea in wrong hands and Murphy will ensure it gets into hundreds pairs of wrong hands.

Comment: I've read your answer twice and I don't get why using `exclude` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: With `exclude` you still bring unnecessary `IStream` declaration onto type library and then exclude fixes this on the other end. Not to mention that there are many other interface which might require the same hack and type library gets more and more bloated. Use of `IUnknown` keeps type library free of junk.

Comment: There are core Windows DLLs suffering from this problem as well. For example, `IMAPI2.DLL` - also drags `IStream` into the type library. There is little point in taking lots of junk on board and then using exclusion lists to get things back resolved.

Comment: I see your point. Here's what happens in the `QI()` scenario http://stackoverflow.com/q/16590106/57428 Suppose I don't care about the solution being elegant (typelib bloat) - will `exclude` just work?

Comment: Exclude is one of the ways but I don't see how exclusion will map type library `IStream` into well known `IStream`. Instead, I would expect the exclusion works as follows: no `IStream` on import, and parameter is degraded into `IUnknown`. This is not so much different from my method above under "Callee" since it will require QI/cast on the importer side. Importing into namespace is another workaround, but you anyway will have to cast in code between `IStream`s.

Comment: Exclusion will map it pretty easily - you can see in the emitted .tlh that there's not forward-declaration of `IStream` inside the namespace when `exclude` is used, so the previously declared `IStream` from the global namespace is used.

Comment: @sharptooth: you are correct, it leaves `IStream` on `.tlh` and connects it to earlier defined.